# How can I enforce the unit tests to use the main applications root path but not the TestResults?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, io

I use Microsoft Visual Studio test Tools assembly for unit testing.

And from one of my unit tests, I test a class which loads a text file.

The problem is, at the time the unit test runs, the root directory of becoms:

C:\Users\Foo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject\TestResults\Foo_HisComputer 2012-07-03 13_50_45\Out

And that is why the file is not found.

How can I enforce the unit test runtime to use the main application's root path but not the TestResults folder which it generates after each Unit Test run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the text file to the output :

```
[TestClass]
[DeploymentItem("textfile.txt")]
public class BaseUnitTest
{
}
```

You need to set the text file in the project and copy it to the ouput folder.

Otherwise, maybe this link can help you :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243187.aspx

Comment: How about copying a folder? I have many files in a folder called Templates.

Comment: Just put the folder name instead of the fileName. [DeploymentItem("myfolder")]

Comment: I found it and did it like this: [DeploymentItem("Folder\\", "Folder\\")]